# $cordovaOauth in ios 9 Device 'redirect_url'

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I use $cordovaOauth in iOs for authenticate in Google, Twitter and Facebook. My problem is that the redirect_url is open when I don't want to open. Is there any way? In Android I haven't this problem.

Thanks and regards.

My code:

```
 $cordovaOauth.facebook(SOCIAL_MEDIA.ID_FACEBOOK, ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'], {redirect_uri:"http://www.web.com/"}).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result.access_token);
                $http.post('http://' + CONFIG.SERVER + '/api/auth/async/facebook?accessToken=' + result.access_token).success(function(data, status, headers) {
                    $state.go('perfilE-Relato.listaDeRelatos');
                    TokenIdStorage.store(headers(CONFIG.TOKEN_ID))
                    TokenRefreshStorage.store(headers(CONFIG.TOKEN_REFRESH));
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    MyService.mostrarPopUpAlert('Error ' + CONFIG.SERVER, status + " | " + headers + " | " + config);
                });
            }, function(error) {
                MyService.mostrarPopUpAlert('ERROR', error);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was using the app Ionic View and this not support $cordovaOauth.